# Cosmosdb create and object with properties from sub query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

hello I have items like that :

```
parent   : { partitionKey:"pk", id="xx" }

children : { partitionKey:"pk", id="yy", parentId="xx" }
```

I would like to return an object like that

```
{ partitionKey:"a", id="xx", children: [{ partitionKey:"a", id="yy", parent-id="xx" },.. ] }
```

I can get the children and parent like that:

```
SELECT * FROM pk a where a.id= "xx"
SELECT * FROM pk a where a.parentId= "xx"
```

and tried

```
SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM pk a where a.parentId= "xx") as children FROM pk a where a.id= "xx"
```

but it returns syntax error near ,

Comment: I'm a little confused as I'm not quite sure what the shape of the data is you are trying to query. But what I do notice in your question, you alias for the collection and child array is not correct.  Take a look at this article here, I think the example in just this doc will give you the example you're looking for, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started Hope that helps.

Comment: hello @MarkBrown thank you for the link. I have read it already but I style don't understand the "from" part ?
"from c" seems to be from container, and "from a" seems to be from partition?

The shape of the data is basic let's say an item with a name, id, partitionkey property and an unbounded list of children that have name, id, partitionkey and reference to the parent parentId. and at the end of the day I would like to get the list of children embed in the parent.

I have see the ARRAY key word but it seems to work only for value

Comment: You don't alias partitions in Cosmos. "From c" is simply a way to reference the underlying container so you can provide an alias for those properties that are either in your where clause or will be projected. For subqueries you reference the path and alias those too. Maybe this article will help you more. Overall, if you are new to Cosmos, I recommend reading the Query docs, writing queries over JSON data is different than SQL because of the hierarchical data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this using query :

```
select (select * from p where p.id = "xx") as parent ,(select * from p where p.parentId ="xx") as child from p
```

and combine all child elements as an array by code will be a workaround.